# Complex roles and permissions model on nested group structure in Keycloak

Tags: authorization, keycloak

I have an application where all user permissions and roles are handled in a database (homemade permission model), but since user authentication now needs to be moved to Keycloak I am looking into if these permission model can be supported by roles and authorization in Keycloak also.

The object model in the application is a nested tree structure with three types of objects (picture provided for details)

[image: Object model]

There are a number of `Grouping Objects`, under each of them there are a number of `Main Objects` and under each of these there can be a hierarchy tree of `Tree Objects`. Each object  at any level can be assigned roles (different for each object type), such as `Owner`, `Contributor`, `Reader` and on each object type there are a number of different types of permissions (also different for each object type), such as `Create child object`, `Add users` etc.

Currently my thoughts are to create the structure as groups in `Keycloak` and put users in the groups when they are allowed access to it, but I am stuck in figuring out if I can handle the different roles and permissions individually for each user when they are assigned to a group - and if the complexity is too high when i need to sync the tree structure as the objects still needs to exists in my database also. Note, there can be 500k of objects.

Currently some roles also overwrite permissions in the subtree, such that if you is an Owner of a `Grouping Object` you are allowed all no matter if there for some reason is a more strict permissions in a sub object.

Any advice or resource reference are much appreciate, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think what you are trying to achive here, is possible with Keycloak out of the box. Keep in mind that roles are related to the realm or individual clients.
When you assign a (realm/client) role R to a group G and add a user U to that group G, the user U will be assigned that role R for the corresponding realm/client and not for the group.

If your grouping/main/tree objects are business objects (or data) within your app, keep them there. Let Keycloak handle authentication, authorization enforcement should be responsibility of your app.

Comment: "authorization enforcement should be responsibility of your app", in your opinion the keycloak authorization feature is not rich enough to justify its used? I am asking because I fell it is easier to handle on the backend. But generally should the IDP also handle that (if possible)

Comment: @dreamcrash Enforcement not decision making. [Authorization Services](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/authorization_services/) can be used for decision making, of course. But be aware of the potential implications that may come with it (like increased number of request to Keycloak). When authorization logic is heavily based on the data stored within a client, I don't think it is justifiable to implement the logic in Keycloak. But that is opinionated and debatable. Too less information here in a stackoverflow post to really make a meaningful architectural decision.